# Manipulating backstack from a service

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

I have a service that is started from an activity/fragment, MainActivity. A list is populated from broadcasts from the service. The user can click a list item and see item details in a details activity/fragment, DetailsActivity. The service will generate one or more notifications that corresponds to the items in the list, as they are added.

The user can go directly to the details activity/fragment, DetailsActivity, by pulling down the notifications and clicking on one of the notifications.

I have set the manifest to indicate the proper parent activity, and added the pendingIntent to the backstack using stackBuilder ([As seen here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)).

**When starting the DetailsActivity from a notification, using the back button to destroy the activity, I end up back at the launcher, rather than in the MainActivity, where I want to be. Where have I gone wrong?**

This is Android version 4.03

Here is the code in the service that creates the notification:

```
Context ctx = getBaseContext();
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(ctx, DetailsActivity.class);
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(ctx);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(uniquePendingIntentID, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

mNotificationMgr = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx);
builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_small)
        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentTitle("New list item found")
        .setContentText("Found a new list item: " + itemName)
        .setPriority(Notification.FLAG_HIGH_PRIORITY);
mNotificationMgr.notify(Integer.parseInt(deviceId), builder.build());
```

The manifest items of interest are:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.something.MainActivity"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_main"
    android:label="@string/main_title"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.something.DetailsActivity">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.something.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this exact issue on various Android platforms: 4.1, 4.2 and even 4.4. The strange thing is that it appeared to be dependent on the device. For example, on a Nexus 4 with Android 4.4.2, it didn't work, but on a Galaxy S4 with Android 4.4, it worked! Furthermore, on a Cyanogenmod Android 4.3.1 Galaxy S2, it worked.

Comment: If you have found any solution please share it. Please take care over your answers to be useful for solving the problem. [This guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) may interest you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you call addParentStack(MainActivity.class) you add the parent of MainActivity to the stack (so nothing as your MainActivity has no parent).

What you're looking for addNextIntentWithParentStack(yourIntent) which will add the parent stack of yourIntent to the stack, and then add yourItent.